# Power BI hybrid dataset reports on dashboard not updating

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

We are using a Pro trial account for Power BI. We are using a hybrid dataset (that's streaming and push) in Power BI. We successfully create dashboards using streaming tiles which can get refreshed as expected using the Card visualization.

However, when we create a simple report (using a slicer) and pin that report to the dashboard, we don't see live updates without refreshing the browser. Can anyone advise why the dashboard does not continue updating?